# Smart pointers to within a smart-pointer managed array

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am writing a C++ wrapper around a low-level object that's stored in a character array.  I would like to be able to manage the lifetime of my class using smart pointers.  Several members of my class need to return pointers into the object; since these are not separate allocations, I cannot use the standard smart pointers for them and these pointers will become invalid once the main object is released.

For concreteness, consider the following simple string class:

```
class 
String
{
    char* s;
    size_t len;

protected:
    String(const char* str) {
        len = std::strlen(str);
        s = new char[len];
        std::strcpy(s, str);
    }
public:
    ~String() {
        delete s;
    }

    char*
    getString() {
        return s;
    }

    char*
    getSubstr(size_t idx) {
        if (idx < len)
            return &s[idx];
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<String>
    makeString(const char* str) {
        return std::shared_ptr<String>(new String(str));
    }
};
```

I can manage instances of `String` using `std::shared_ptr`.  But when my `String` object gets destroyed, any pointers returned by `getString()` or `getSubstring()` will be invalid.  I would *like* to have a way for `getString()` and `getSubstring()` to return some sort of smart pointer that will hold a reference to the parent object so the the following code is valid:

```
std::shared_ptr<String> str = String::makeString("Hello world");
SOMETHING<char> substr = str->getSubstr(6);

std::printf("String: %s\n", str->getString());
str.reset();
std::printf("Substring: %s\n", substr.get());
```

Is there any way to achieve this using standard C++ functionality?  If not, what about Boost?

**Update**

Here's a version that seems to work (when compiled as C++11 using gcc or clang), based on Yakk's suggestions:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::enable_shared_from_this;

class 
String : public enable_shared_from_this<String>
{
    size_t len;
    char* s;

protected:
    String(const char* str) : len(std::strlen(str)), s(new char[len]) {
        std::copy(str, str+len, s);
    }
public:
    ~String() {
        delete s;
    }

    shared_ptr<char[]>
    getString() {
        return shared_ptr<char[]>(shared_from_this(), s);
    }

    shared_ptr<char[]>
    getSubstr(size_t idx) {
        if (idx < len)
            return shared_ptr<char[]>(shared_from_this(), s+idx);
        else
            return shared_ptr<char[]>();
    }

    static shared_ptr<String>
    makeString(const char* str) {
         return shared_ptr<String>(new String(str));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the `shared_ptr` "aliasing" constructor.

If you have C++1z support, you'll even get `[]`.

Your "SOMETHING" is just `shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<char>
getSubstr(size_t idx) {
    if (idx < len)
        return {shared_from_this(), &s[idx]};
    else
        return {};
}
```

and add `enable_shared_from_this` to `String`.

Alternatively, manage the buffer directly via a `shared_ptr` within `String`:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> s;
```

and

```
String(const char* str) {
    len = std::strlen(str);
    s = std::shared_ptr<char>(new char[len], std::default_deleter<char[]>{});
    std::strcpy(s.get(), str);
}

std::shared_ptr<char>
getSubstr(size_t idx) {
    if (idx < len)
        return {s, s.get()+idx};
    else
        return {};
}
```

The advantage of this strategy is that `String` need not be managed by a shared ptr -- you can stick it in a vector or declare it on the stack.  C++ thrives on Regular types like that.

The internal buffer meanwhile is smart pointer managed, so substrings cannot dangle.

The core of this is the aliasing constructor.  Shared pointers have 2 components: a reference counting block, and a data pointer.

The reference counting block has a strong count, a weak count, and a destruction function.

The aliasing constructor lets you use a different shared pointer's reference counting block, and an arbitrary data pointer.  This is intended for returning shared pointers to members of a class which is managed by a shared pointer, which is basically what you are doing.